How to filter Google Places API autocomplete results before displaying them to the user?
I am working on a web application that uses the Google Places API to provide address suggestions for postal codes and towns. I need to filter the autocomplete results based on a specific regex pattern before they are displayed to the user. Specifically, I need to filter Dutch postal codes (NL) to ensure they match the following regex pattern:
/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i
This pattern ensures that the postal code:

Starts with a digit from 1 to 9
Is followed by three digits (0-9)
May have a space
Ends with two letters, excluding certain combinations (sa, sd, ss)

Here is my current implementation:
private initPlacesForPostalCodeAndTown(input: HTMLInputElement): Promise<GoogleResponsePostalCodeAndTown> {
    const options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: this.getSelectedCountryIso() },
        fields: ["address_components"],
        types: ["postal_code"],
    };
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            const googleResponse = {} as GoogleResponsePostalCodeAndTown;
            const postalCodePattern = /^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i;

            for (const component of place.address_components) {
                const componentType = component.types[0];

                switch (componentType) {
                    case "postal_code":
                        googleResponse.postalCode = component.long_name;
                        break;
                    case "locality":
                    case "postal_town":
                        googleResponse.town = component.long_name;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (this.getSelectedCountryIso() === "nl" && googleResponse.postalCode && !postalCodePattern.test(googleResponse.postalCode)) {
                // Do not resolve if postal code does not match the pattern
                return;
            }

            resolve(googleResponse);
        });
    });
}


The place_changed event in the Google Places API is fired after the user has already seen the autocomplete suggestions, which is too late for my filtering needs. I want to ensure that only valid Dutch postal codes are shown in the suggestions list. The filtering requirement is specific to Dutch postal codes, but the solution should ideally not interfere with other countries' results.
Is there any way to filter the suggestions before they are rendered to the user? Perhaps using a different event or a workaround? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service

Not sure why you would need to filter postal codes if you already added a country component restriction. Anyway, if you want full control on what is displayed and how, you should use the Autocomplete Service (link in the comment above). See this answer for a complete example on how to build a custom autocomplete solution.

@MrUpsidown A Dutch zip code always has two letters after the digits. Unfortunately, there are also “invalid” zip codes listed that are missing these two letters. I would like to remove these entries from the list.

So you need a workaround, and that workaround is to use the Autocomplete Service class as stated already. But this is a data issue which you should be reporting. Finding a workaround is good, having correct data in the first place is better.
